# Bootstrap : navtab and dropdown button alignement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying create a simple responsive design with fixed-top navbar using the CSS twitter boostrap framework. I get an issue around dropdown button in nav tab.

My problem is that when I add the css "pull-right" on a dropdown button, the dropdown is displayed out of the screen.

Here is the code/example: http://jsfiddle.net/MbJ97/1/

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group">
```

Do you know how to fix this ?
Also what is the best way to add some spacing between the text and the button ?

Regards,
Cedric.

Comment: Seems fine to me - chrome Mac

Comment: Wow, did you click on the button arrow to display the menu (dropdown) ? The menu is cut and 50% is openned outside the windows for me...

Comment: Chrome also... Windows.

Comment: I'm talking about the blue button! On the right of the top navbar ;-)